# colorful syntax highlighter for joomla

Tags: php, joomla

syntax highlighter for Joomla so far, does not work. I tried both the plugin and the download folder from the actual site. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

1. I tried both using < and < for the pre tag. Is it supposed to be only the first < that changes or both < and >?
2. Either way, (plugin activated or done manually with the folder) the pre tag always shows up... suddenly however, the code is executed instead of being shown. Before the pre tag, it would just show all the tags as normal text.

Below is the links to the folder I downloaded and the files needed. Not sure if i am missing something...

```
    <!--BEGIN SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTER-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css" type="text/css" />
    <!---->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushAS3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushPhp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushSql.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushPlain.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/includes/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shThemeDjango.css" type="text/css" />
```

I really want this to work, if anything are there other suggestions for Joomla syntax highlighting? Something really colorful if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `lang` attribute?

i.e.

```
<pre lang="html">
your html
</pre>
```

Comment: yes i have, it still doesn't work... ive tried 
<pre class=”brush:html" lang="html">, 
<pre lang="html">
<pre class=”brush:html">...nothing